# Best practice for managing multiple UINavigationController stacks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application where I have 3 `UINavigation` Stacks that can be switched between each other via a custom menu. When switching from Stack A to either Stack B or C, it looks like the new section is being pushed onto the current navigation stack, as the RootViewController for Stacks B/C both have back buttons that pop back to the previous stack. User's can either navigate back to Stack A using the custom menu, or by hitting the back button on Stack B/C RootViewController, which brings them back to where they were in Stack A.

The problem I'm having is figuring out the best way to keep track of whether a user is in Stack A. If they are on the 4th drill down in Stack A, switch to Stack B, and then switch back to Stack A, I need to show exactly where they previously were in Stack A's flow.

Should I be using multiple `UINavigationController`s, or is there perhaps a way to achieve this without as much hassle (i.e. possibly using `UIViewController` Containment)?

Comment: What code are you currently using to switch between the three navigation controllers? It sounds like you need to be using something like a tab bar controller (with the navigation bar hidden) so you have a container controller to house your 3 stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use containment to somehow change the navigation controller, yes, but you certainly don't need to do that. You can grab the whole stack within a UINavigationController before replacing it and keep track of your 3 stacks, in a structure like an array or dictionary.

```
typedef {
   Section1,
   Section2,
   Section3
} Section;

..

@property (nonatomic, assign) Section currentSection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray currentStacks; //Initialize this was the base stacks for each section (i.e an NSArray with just 1 controller for each slot)
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;

..

- (void)setSection:(Section)section
{
    self.stacks[self.currentSection] = [self.navigationController.controllers copy];//Save stack for the current section
    [self.navigationController setViewController:self.stacks[section] animated:YES];
    self.currentSection = section;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have any problems with performance, my proposition is to keep all required view controller stacks inside separate **UINavigationControl**-s. So you would have as many navigation controller objects as items in your menu. In this case you would have rather less problems and your logic would be cleaner.

This approach doesn't require much memory, because the most consumable thing is **UIView** hierarchy and not **UIViewController**-s or **UINavigationController**-s.